# How to design excel sheet using maatwebsite in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have exported excel CSV file using `maatwebsite` package in `laravel`. But when I export it, it's show the raw data, how can I design this excel for show every data separately with it's title.

Here, is my exported data image link.
http://prntscr.com/i08up8
Here is excel export code.

```
 public function export()
{
  $items = DB::table('userinformations')
        ->join('users', 'userinformations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('userinformations.fname','userinformations.lname','users.email')
        ->where('userinformations.payment_status',1)
        ->get();
    $items=array($items);
  Excel::create('items', function($excel) use($items) {
      $excel->sheet('ExportFile', function($sheet) use($items) {
          $sheet->fromArray($items);
      });
  })->export('csv');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line:

```
 $items=array($items);
```

Laravel returns a collection. So this would mean you put the entire collection in an (one) array.

Try this instead:

```
$items = $items->toArray();
```

This will cast your collection to an array and should solve your issue